# How to add a value in Firebase to a Label in xcode?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been Searching for 2 days on the internet now, and no sign of this. All i want to do is to take a value from RealTimeDataBase and put it in my label, apparently i can't find an answer and the people in youtube do it in a TableViewController. I tried some code but it doesn't work:

my code:

```
struct mylist {
        let title :  String!
    }
    var ref: DatabaseReference?


    @IBOutlet var LabelTest: UILabel!

    var posts = [mylist]()

    @IBAction func nextTapped(_ sender: Any) {
//
//






          let ref = Database.database().reference()


        ref.child("ServiceA").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { DataSnapshot in

           let value = DataSnapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            let title = value?["ServiceA"] as? String
            self.posts.insert(mylist(title: title), at: 0)
   })
        post()

    }




    func post() {

        let title = "Title"
        let post = ["title": title]
       let ref = Database.database().reference()
        ref.child("ServiceA").childByAutoId().setValue(post)

        LabelTest.text = mylist.title
    }
```

please help me
i tried to follow this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XIQsQ2injLo

Comment: is it that im dumb or is there no way to do this?

Comment: Make sure you update your UI on the main thread.

Comment: how do you do that, look, i want to assign a var to the data in the databse, and then assign the var to the textfield.text

Comment: Have you checked if `post()` is called, and if `myList.title` has the expected value? To update your label on the main thread, you could try this: `DispatchQueue.main.async { LabelTest.text = mylist.title }`

Comment: ah thanks for the answer but i found a better way which works... is it possible to answer your own question?

Comment: Yes, you can answer your own question.

Comment: done. thanks for the answer tho

Answer (score 0):

FINALLY!!!

ok so here's how i did it:

```
let ref = Database.database().reference()



func getIncome() {
    ref.child("ServiceA").child("Title").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { DataSnapshot in

        print(DataSnapshot)     
        let m = DataSnapshot.value as? String
        self.LabelTest.text = m
    })
}
```

ok special thanks to koen, his method works to :)

Comment: Even if this works, you should always update your UI on the main thread, also in in your solution.

Comment: @koen Firebase closures automatically update UI calls on the main thread. The networking calls are in the background.

Comment: @Jay Thanks for explaining - I didn't know that.